Access. Tablas. Propieades de búsqueda. Cuadros combinados. Tipo de origen de la fila
He buscado información sobre la utilidad práctica o un ejemplo práctico de para qué se usa esta opción. Dejo captura de la misma. Entiendo perfectamente tanto el origen de la fila tabla/consulta como el de lista de valores. Tanto el procedimiento como el objetivo de para qué usarlos. Pero el de lista de campos no consigo saber para qué lo querría. Ni en una tabla ni en un formulario.

He probado y logro que aparezca un desplegable con los nombres de los campos de la tabla/consulta a la que estoy apuntando, pero ¿para qué querría esto?, esa es la cuestión que estoy planteando. Alguien que haya usado esta opción y que pueda aclararme tanto para qué la ha usado como dónde. Si en tablas, formularios. Y con qué objetivo.

No lo sé exactamente pero tiene pinta de que es para restringir/filtrar por un campo en concreto de la tabla indicada en "Origen de la fila".

Al final, creo que su utilidad, como dices es para formularios con temas dinámicos. Poder elegir crear un informe según el filtro de un determinado campo. De ahí que se muestren campos en el desplegable. Muchas gracias por darme ese enfoque. No había caído en la cuenta. Una lástima que nadie en youtube tenga un vídeo al respecto de cómo realizar la misión.
